# subnet in reflexive spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a reflexive banach space. Let $(a_i)$ be a net in $X$ such that

$$          \liminf_{i} \| a_i \| = \alpha \in R$$

Then can we conclude that there exist a subnet of $(a_i)$ which is weakly convergent ?

If the answer is no in general, what if $X$ be a separable Hilbert space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space. Let $a:D\rightarrow X$ be a
net in $X$, where $(D,\preceq)$ is a directed system. Suppose that
$\liminf_{i}||a_{i}||=\alpha\in[0,\infty)$.

Firstly, we show that there exists a bounded subnet of $a$. For each
$i\in D$, define $\beta_{i}=\inf\{||a_{j}||\mid j\in D\mbox{ and }i\preceq j\}\in[0,\infty)$.
Then we obtain a net of non-negative real numbers $\beta:D\rightarrow[0,\infty)$,
$i\mapsto\beta_{i}$. Clearly, the net $\beta$ is monotonic increasing.
By assumption, $\lim_{i}\beta_{i}=\alpha<\infty$. Hence $\beta(i)\leq\alpha<\infty$
for all $i\in D$. For each $i\in D$, let $A_{i}=\{j\in D\mid||a_{j}||<\alpha+1\mbox{ and }i\preceq j\}$,
which is non-empty because $\beta_{i}<\alpha+1\Rightarrow\alpha+1$
is not a lower bound of the set $\{||a_{j}||\mid j\in D\mbox{ and }i\preceq j\}$.
By the Axiom of Choice, there exists a function $\theta:D\rightarrow\bigcup_{i\in D}A_{i}\subseteq D$
such that $\theta(i)\in A_{i}$. Let $b=a\circ\theta:D\rightarrow X$.
Note that $\theta$ is a co-final map from $D$ into $D$: For, let
$i_{0}\in D$ be arbitrary. Let $j_{0}=i_{0}$. For any $j\in D$
with $j_{0}\preceq j$, we have $\theta(j)\in A_{j}$, which implies
that $j\preceq\theta(j)$ by the very definition of $A_{j}$. That
is, $i_{0}\preceq j$ and $j\preceq\theta(j)$, which further implies
that $i_{0}\preceq\theta(j)$ by the transitive property of direction
$\preceq$. This shows that $\theta$ is a co-final map and hence
$b$ is a subnet of $a$. By the way we construct $\theta$, for each
$i\in D$, $||b(i)||=||a(\theta(i))||<\alpha+1$. Therefore, $b$
is a bounded subnet of $a$.

By assumption, $X^{\ast\ast}=X$ (more accurately, $X^{\ast\ast}$
is isometric isomorphic to the image of $X$ in $X^{\ast\ast}$ via
the canonical embedding $x\mapsto\hat{x}$, where $\hat{x}(f)=f(x),$
$f\in X^{\ast}$). Regard $b$ as a bounded net in $(X^{\ast})^{\ast}$
and recall that every bounded ball of $(X^{\ast})^{\ast}$ (bounded
ball means the set $\{\xi\in X^{\ast\ast}\mid||\xi||\leq r\}$, for
some $r\in[0,\infty)$) is $\sigma(X^{\ast\ast},X^{\ast})$-compact
(the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem), so $b$ further has a subnet $c$ which
is convergent with respect to the $\sigma(X^{\ast\ast},X^{\ast})$-topology
on $X^{\ast\ast}$. Clearly $c$ is a subnet of $a$. Moreover, since
$X^{\ast\ast}=X$, the $\sigma(X^{\ast\ast},X^{\ast})$-topology is
actually the $\sigma(X,X^{\ast})$-topology on $X$. In short, $a$
has a subnet $c$ which is convergent with respect to the weak topology.

Comment: Please do not trust me too much because everything in above relies on my memory in 1999. I do not have any textbook about general topology nor functional analysis on my hand anymore...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** There is a bounded subnet...

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I'm not sure the liminf defined by net  exactly has same properties as it does with sequences .

Comment: @Redshoes So work out the bits you're not sure about! A sequence witth a finite lim inf has a bounded subsequence; what part of the proof of  that goes wrong for nets?

Comment: I didn't say it goes wrong. I'm saying constructing that bounded subnet is pretty much the question I asked, but you took it for granted. Situation for sequence can be done in one line, but when it comes to nets constructing subnet is not that trivial you think.

Comment: It's trivial - the fact that Danny took 13 lines to write out every detail and every definition does not show it's not. Since you say "constructing that bounded subnet is pretty much the question I asked" it seems you agree that getting  from a bounded subnet to a convergent subnet is trivial, but he took 8 lines for _that_.

Comment: Btw if you realized that you were done if you had a bounded subnet you should have said so, to clarify what parts of your homework you wanted done for you...

Comment: When problems get solved, they become trivial for everyone. I try to admit  that it is trivial for you, although from saying  that "what part of the proof of that goes wrong for nets?"  clearly implies you had same line of proof for net in your mind as you had for sequence!  And the one you said about extracting convergent subnet from a bounded net in reflexive spaces,  it is well-known and can be cited to every textbooks I knew that, that's not case the question I asked.  Also if the question itself is not clear for you, I clarified for you in the comment see above!

Comment: And If you have got ultra knowledge that makes you recognize  a Op's question is his/her homework or not, dont you think it's stupid to make effort to provide answer for it. Isn't better just  pass it